# Marketing Cloud-Auto generate Subscriber key

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber

Wondering is there anyway we can auto generate Subscriber key?

In our case, Contacts come from Sales Cloud to Marketing Cloud so we have the ID as the Subscriber key but there are some cases some subscribers are manually created in marketing cloud so we would like to auto generate in those cases and don't want to ask the users to enter unique key.

Would appreciate your insight and also the best practice in this case.

Comment: Are you using the Mobile Push Android and/or iOS SDKs?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. It is best practice is use the external system id as the subscriber key . In the case where subscribers are created in the marketing cloud, the system will use email address as the subscriber key.

Excerpt from documentation:

> Use a unique value that does not relate to a specific channel. If you
>   import a value from an external data source, ensure you import that
>   value to a string-based field, even if the external data source uses a
>   number as the unique identifier. If you use your Marketing Cloud
>   account to gather data, consider using a GUID or other generated ID in
>   a string field as the Contact Key value.

Although this is focussed on contact builder, the same logic applies with email studio.

**Resources**

- [Contact Builder Best Practices](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/contact_builder_best_practices/)